# Как добавить Fraction() в TKinter Entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```py
from fractions import Fraction

def main():
    a = Fraction(input("Введите первую дробь: "))
    b = Fraction(input("Введите вторую дробь: "))
    print(a + b)
    print(a - b)
    print(a * b)
    print(a / b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Как такой код использовать с Tk entry?
python: 3.8.0
Спасибо за внимание()

Comment: Точно так же как если бы нужно было вводить любой другой тип чисел.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
...
text = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(master, textvariable = text)
text.set('any text or var')
...
```